# Can't use Storage service inside custom auth service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

For some reason I am having trouble accessing the storage service and setting storage properties with my custom auth service.

I have a login method that should hit my API, get a token, decode the token and store the user information via storage. This all works if I do this in the login promise but that seems like an anti-pattern to me.

I've imported the storage module...

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

And injected into the constructor...

```
constructor(private http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
    return this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.contentHeader })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And then when I try to use it in the response from the `http` service...

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  this.error = null;
  this.user = body.user[0];
  this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
    this.storage.set('profile',this.user);
    this.storage.set('token',body.token);
  });
  return body || {};
}
```

I get the error

```
Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

I can't seem to find online how it should work within a service differently from within a module.

Comment: Why not using `window.localStorage` ?

Comment: It's unlikely that injected service will be undefined. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe it's not related to this, but just in case, use arrow functions to keep the `this` keyword pointing to the component. So instead of `function() { ... }` use `() => { ... }`

Comment: I updated the code to show how to functions are laid out just in case it points to some error in my syntax

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to set storage values.

Comment: @YuvrajPatil I updated the `extractData` function to show how I'm trying to use storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a context variable for `this` reference. Your code should look like below:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  let context = this;
  this.error = null;
  this.user = body.user[0];
  this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
    context.storage.set('profile',context .user);
    context.storage.set('token',body.token);
  });
  return body || {};
}
```

Comment: The arrow syntax already does the same thing.  The `this` inside the `then` will refer to the same thing in the `extractData` method. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @echonax It may be possible that he (Jordan) has made a async call inside    current arrow function but he had not shared the code. So my answer can be helpful for him for that scenario.

Comment: In that case your answer might have been correct but the problem lies within the call of the `extractData` method. It doesn't have the lexical `this`. It should've been like `.map(this.extractData.bind(this))` or `.map((res)=>this.extractData(res))`. I haven't written it as an answer because this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @echonax this ended up being my issue. I got confused with how the function was being executed. I'm still wrapping my head around this es6 stuff

Comment: @Jordan then can you please mark your question as a duplicate with the link I've provided?